# Is this word slang? アメテ

Tags: translation, meaning, slang, child-speech

I can't find a definition for this word `アメテ`. Aside from sounding like an amateur, the word didn't make sense in the context.

In the context, a character was flipping out. The entire sentence he screamed was:

> アメテ!!

Is this just a random sound he made or... what?

The sentence before ended with してるわけ!! if that helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

アメテ! is baby speech for やめて! (Stop it!).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks.  Can't believe it was that simple.